# ERROR: Failed to configure trigger GCS Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-functions

While issuing command `gcloud beta functions deploy` I get following error message in Terminal: `ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13, message=Failed to configure trigger GCS Bucket: 18_bucket`

Even tried to make simple function in Web UI (https://console.cloud.google.com/) I get same error (attach screenshot)

- Trigger type: Cloud Storage bucket
- Event Type: Finalize/Create

I believe i'm doing everything correct, even tried same steps in other Cloud Project, only in this Project (new project created few hours back) I get an error! Any idea what could be issues...

NOTE:

- Already tried Disable & Re-enable Cloud Functions API
- both GCS Bucket & Cloud Function is in same project

Thanks a lot for any clue into it..

**UPDATE**: *ok, created fresh new project > Enabled Billing > Enabled Cloud Functions API > Created GCS Bucket > Create New Function (google.storage.object.finalize) > keeps giving same error: `Deployment failure: Failed to configure trigger GCS Bucket: {{BUCKET NAME}}`. HTTP Triggers works fine though*

[image]

Comment: Same error for me. I tried on a newly created project, it fails too. I tried on a billing project, it failed too. I tried old API and new API (onFinalize), both failed.

Comment: Same here. Contacted Google support, waiting for an answer.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.. looks like some backend issue with newly created projects. Existing Projects continue to work fine

Comment: I'm having the same issue... I've also contacted support.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been solved by Google and was not related to our code :

https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18024#5700609697120256

Comment: I can confirm it's been solved. Just curious though, how is this related to Firebase?